# Not able to push when implementing linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

here's part of my code for the linked list:

```
struct node {
    float data;
    int key;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *current;
    int length;
} linked_list;

linked_list *init_list(){
    linked_list *out = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
    out->head = head;
    out->current = current;
    out->length = 0;
    return out;
}

void push_core(struct node *head, int key, float data){
    struct node *link = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    link->data = data;
    link->key = key;
    link->next = head;
    // readjust to point at the new first node
    head = link;
    printf("%f; ", head->data);
}
void push(linked_list *list, int key, float data){
    push_core(list->head, key, data);
    list->length ++;
}

void print_list_core(struct node *head){
    struct node* ptr = head;
    printf("\n[");
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("(%d,%f)", ptr->key, ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void print_list(linked_list *list){
    print_list_core(list->head);
}
```

But in the main, after I initialized the linked list structure, I wasn't able to use push() to link new pointers, why is that?

```
linked_list *S = init_list();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    push(S,i,0);
    print_list(S);
    printf("%d;", S->length);
}
```

To clarify, the length of the list does update correctly. But when I try to print the list it doesn't work. Also, it's interesting that in another file when I initially just worked with the node struct and defined global variables for head and current, the code works fine. But when I try to wrap them up inside this linked_list struct, things aren't quite working as expected.

Comment: The C language passes function arguments by value. So updating `head` in `push_core` doesn't do anything to the `head` pointer in the `list` structure.

Comment: @user3386109 I thought I passed a pointer so it should write on that? So how should I edit the code to make it work? Should I change that to a double pointer? Thanks!

Comment: Can you debug your code?

Comment: If I was writing the code, I'd get rid of the `push_core` and `print_list_core` functions, and just implement `push` and `print_list`.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but there are quite a few issues that you should look into with the debugger

Comment: @JackLilhammers Sorry, I should use the debugger first. I was just not very familiar with the standard debugging process.

Comment: @user3386109 I didn't use these wrapping functions first, but I was wondering if I get rid of these, then I my code has to do more dereferencing in general? Or if that is not the case?

Comment: It's really not that hard. Now I'm assuming you're using Windows, but on other platforms is the same. You can use Code::Blocks, which is a nice little IDE http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: @JackLilhammers Thanks, I will have a look. I'm on mac and I've tried to use gdb, but I'm still getting familiar with the process.

Comment: Let's take `print_list` as an example. The call to `print_list_core` essentially converts `list->head` to `head` and then the first line of `print_list_core` converts `head` to `ptr`. You could simply write `struct node *ptr = list->head;` in the `print_list` function to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense, sorry about this awkward code style! And I see that I shouldn't get this problem if I don't use these extra functions.

Comment: No problem, live and learn. Best of luck to you!  And in response to the edit: yup, that's exactly right.

Comment: Gosh no. gdb is a great tool, but using the debugger in an IDE is another thing in terms of comfort. There are many Mac compatible IDEs for you to choose, or you can just use XCode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because you passed the pointer value of `list->head` to your `push_code` function as a parameter. This is a function `call-by-value`. So, when you change the `head` pointer inside the `push_core` function, it actually do not change the `list->head` pointer that you are expecting to. One quick fix would be returning the newly created `link` pointer from the `push_core` function and save it as `list->head`. The following code should fix your problem.

```
struct node * push_core(struct node *head, int key, float data){
    struct node *link = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    link->data = data;
    link->key = key;
    link->next = head;
    
    return link;
}

void push(linked_list *list, int key, float data){
    list->head = push_core(list->head, key, data);
    list->length ++;
}
```