# C passing by reference

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want this function to add a point to the beginning of the linked list:

```
void addPoint(Point *head, int x, int y, SDL_bool dir) {
    Point *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    p->dir = dir;
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
}
```

The head is initialized earlier like so:

```
Point *down = NULL;
```

Afterwards I call the function like so:

```
addPoint(&down, x * grid_cell_width, (y - 1) * grid_cell_height, SDL_FALSE);
```

Unfortunately this does not work as After after the call the head is still NULL.

Comment: One of the *many* duplicates of this problem [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis). Another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66252089/not-able-to-push-when-implementing-linked-list-in-c). Both discovered by simply putting `[c] linked list push head update fails`. There are *hundreds* of others you can review as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this part right:

```
addPoint(&down,...);
```

but the type of the expression `&down` is `Point **`, not `Point *`, so you need to change the definition of `addPoint` to

```
void addPoint(Point **head, int x, int y, SDL_bool dir) {
    ...
    p->next = *head;
    *head = p;
}
```

With this code, you have the following relationships:

```
 head == &down // Point ** == Point **
*head ==  down // Point * == Point *
```

So in the `addPoint` function, writing to `*head` is the same as writing to `down`.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer to `head`, meaning you are passing a copy of the address of `head` to function `addPoint`. In the line where you are changing the value of `head` you are actually modifying the local pointer. To change that, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, like so:

```
void addPoint(Point **head, int x, int y, SDL_bool dir) {
    Point *p = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    p->dir = dir;
    p->next = head;
    *head = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
void addPoint(Point **head, int x, int y, SDL_bool dir) {
    Point* p = malloc(sizeof(p));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    p->dir = dir;
    p->next = head;
    *head = p;
}
```

In C there is no pass-by-reference mechanism per se, you just pass pointers to arguments instead (in this case, a pointer to a pointer). But those pointers are still just values, so a change to them is not visible outside of the function. What will be visible is a change to the value that the pointer points to. That's why you need to assign your p pointer to the location that the pointer head points to, hence you need to dereference it with (*) operator first.

Comment: The assignment-from `malloc` here is completely wrong, and that alone is an indication something went off the rails. `Point p = malloc(sizeof(p));` shouldn't even compile. (invalid conversion from `void*` to `Point`).

Comment: @WhozCraig As far as I am aware, that is only true for C++, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736833/void-pointers-difference-between-c-and-c . I agree casting it makes it more intentional(which In my opinion is better), but I do not believe it is inherently wrong in this particular context.

Comment: The code now, post change is *almost* correct. Your `sizeof` is still wrong; that's the size of a *pointer*, not the size of a `Point`. My prior comment is/was based on your initial post, and was accurate to that content.